# In UNet model of prediction to test dataset, how to get multiple inference probabilities for each pixel？

Tags: python

I have trained the Unet model,then I predicted test dataset with the trained Unet.In training stage, the patch size is 256×256,and in test stage,the patch size is also 256×256，but strides is 64.that is to say,there is overlapping between patches.After predicting all the patches from test dataset,in the post-processing phase of predicted patches,how to put all the patches which were predicted into category labels together,especially in overlapping part.
How to encode using python? Thanks.

Comment: In general you can use weighted or unweighted upsampling. How to implement one of these depends on the framework.

Comment: it is in precdictions stage.we used a sliding window approach at test time with window size fixed to 256 x 256 and stride of 64. This allowed us to eliminate weaker predictions on image patch boundaries where objects may only be partially shown without context around them.

Comment: I know the UNet Architecture, but I do not understand your Question completly.

Comment: After training Unet, in the prediction of test dataset,how to put all the patches predicted  together into a whole labels?patch size is 256×256,but sample stride is 64×64

Comment: Am I right assuming, that you got the "Colored" segmentation Images? Or do you wondering about the image size?? One big part of the Unet is the copy&crop from left side of the "U" to the right side. In the original Architecture this is done 4 times. So in generell you end up with smaller size results. I also do nor really understand what you talking "a whole labels" about.

Comment: whole labels are the set of patch labels(small images' labels). I already know how to predict the test images. Thank you.

Comment: So is your question now solved?